# Number of Distinct Axiomatic Systems

Tags: logic, axioms

This may well be a vaguely formulated question. Please bear with me and help me modify it to make it meaningful and rigorous, or show that it is hopelessly meaningless.

I understand an axiomatic system is a set of consistent statements. Suppose the number of such statements in each system is finite. Is the number of distinct systems is (countably) infinite?

My conjecture is it is true. I suppose to show it, I assume the contrary, and construct a new system that is distinct from all the prior systems. But I can not see how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's a first-order theory where every model has exactly one element, and a first-order theory where every model has exactly two elements, and so on. There are infinitely many of these first-order theories, none of them equivalent to each other.

These first-order theories can be constructed explicitly by an algorithm. Here's an example of a first-order theory where every model has exactly four elements:

- $a \ne b$.
- $a \ne c$.
- $a \ne d$.
- $b \ne c$.
- $b \ne d$.
- $c \ne d$.
- For all $e$, $e = a$ or $e = b$ or $e = c$ or $e = d$.

This pattern can be continued to get first-order theories where every model has exactly $n$ elements, for any chosen constant $n$. Simply have axioms asserting that no two of $n$ constants are equal to each other, and one final axiom asserting that everything is equal to one of these $n$ constants.

Conversely, any axiomatic system with only finitely many axioms can be written as a string of symbols from a finite alphabet, meaning it can be encoded as an integer. So there must be only countably many such axiomatic systems, up to choice of symbols.

Comment: How do you show the existence of an arbitrary n'th order theory? Is it constructed (without contradiction) from a corresponding (n-1)'th theory? How do we show each of the n'th order theory is (countably, as you have shown) infinite?

Comment: It can be written out explicitly by an algorithm. Here's a first-order theory where every model has exactly four elements: "a ≠ b. a ≠ c. a ≠ d. b ≠ c. b ≠ d. c ≠ d. For all e, e = a or e = b or e = c or e = d." You can do the same for any number *n*: think of *n* constants, then write down axioms asserting that no two of the constants are equal to each other, and then write down one more axiom asserting that everything equals one of the constants.

Comment: Thank you. Can you write your above comment into your answer so as to make future reference more convenient?